# Can angular $resource module return data format other than JSON?

Tags: angularjs, json, dataformat

The website I want to retrieve the data from provides api that I can hit,but I am not sure about the data format of the data,I am not sure if it is JSON or not? and I am not sure if it is array or an object? can somebody have a look at it? cheers.

[image]

This is the request data:

```
 code.service('customerService', ['$resource','baseURL', 
     function($resource,baseURL) {
            this.getAllCustomers = function(){
                return $resource(baseURL,null,{ 'get':  {method:'GET'}});
            };
    }]);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like json

Comment: yeah, it's strange

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions.

Comment: It is csv format of data.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for reminding

Comment: @AnamikaShrivastava do you know that can angular retrieve the csv data?

Comment: @dabeige I am new with angular, But $resource return Object and you can handle this csv in transformResponse  function.

Comment: @AnamikaShrivastava Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `csv` file - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

You can see the headers on the first line

`MemberId - MemberSessionID - CreatedDate - ...`

And the following lines are the data. Each lines represent one record.

The separator used is the comma `,`

Comment: Thanks, and do you know if angular can retrieve csv data?

Comment: AngularJS can retrieve whatever you want. It will returns you the object that it gets. It is your job to correctly handle the data you received :)

Comment: Thanks, knowing it is csv helps alot